# HTML input default value

Tags: html, datetime, input

The following sets an empty initial value in my input box.  Is there a way to force a null value if nothing is entered?

Since it is a `datetime-local` field, I think the empty string is causing me other problems.

```
<td><input id="1stintstart" value="" type="datetime-local"></td>
```

Comment: This was my first post. Not sure what happened to my code sample.    <td><input id="1stintstart" value="" type="datetime-local"></td>

Comment: <td><input id="1stintstart" value="" type="datetime-local"></td>

Comment: You can edit your question, and when you do there's some help available on how to format things (e.g. code).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like a placeholder?

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="test"/>
```